# How to convert PNG to JPG in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to compare two images, one a `.png` and the other a `.jpg`. So I need to convert the `.png` file to a `.jpg` to get closer values for SSIM. Below is the code that I've tried, but I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'

```
image2 = imread(thisPath + caption)
image2 = io.imsave("jpgtest.jpg", (76, 59))
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image2 = resize(image2, (76, 59))
imshow("is it a jpg", image2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Do you not have a [mcve]? One of the answers pointed out that you’re seemingly mixing multiple image processing libraries. Can you clarify things?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Before demonstrating how to convert an image from `.png` to `.jpg` format, I want to point out that you should be consistent on the library that you use. Currently, you're mixing scikit-image with opencv. It's best to choose one library and stick with it instead of reading in an image with scikit and then converting to grayscale with opencv.

To convert a `.png` to `.jpg` image using OpenCV, you can use [`cv2.imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite). Note with `.jpg` or `.jpeg` format, to maintain the highest quality, you must specify the quality value from `[0..100]` (default value is 95). Simply do this:

```
import cv2

# Load .png image
image = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Save .jpg image
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', image, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `skimage.io.imsave` expects you to give it a filename and an array that you want to save under that filename. For example:

```
skimage.io.imsave("image.jpg", image)
```

where `image` is a numpy array.

You are using it incorrectly here:

```
image2 = io.imsave("jpgtest.jpg", (76, 59))
```

you are assigning the output of the `imsave` function to `image2` and I don't think that is what you want to do.

---

You probably don't need to convert the image to JPG because the skimage library already handles all of this conversion by itself. You usually only load the images with `imread` (does not matter whether they are PNG or JPG, because they are represented in a numpy array) and then perform all the necessary computations.

Comment: When not converting and using skimage.measure.compare_ssim on the two pictures (which should be nearly pixel perfect) I'm getting very low values, .2-.4 range or so. Thats why I think I need to convert before I use SSIM.

Answer (score 1):

Python script to convert all .png in the folder into .jpg

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import os
import re

png_file_paths = glob.glob(r"*.png")
for i, png_file_path in enumerate(png_file_paths):
    jpg_file_path = png_file_path[:-3] + "jpg";
   
    # Load .png image
    image = cv.imread(png_file_path)

    # Save .jpg image
    cv.imwrite(jpg_file_path, image, [int(cv.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])

    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use opencv's cvtColor. Assuming image read using cv2.imread(); image color channels arranged as BGR.

To convert from PNG to JPG

```
jpg_img = cv2.cvtColor(png_img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
```

To convert from JPG to PNG

```
png_img = cv2.cvtColor(jpg_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
```